# How can I iterate through a Pandas dataframe and get the value for all columns associated with a given datetime, forward filling values that are -1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose you have a pandas dataframe with 5 columns: one called `code` which contains a string, one named named `calendardate` of `datetime` format, which contains date and time information, and three others named `A`, `B` and `C`, each containing an integer from -1 to 100.

For each code value, there can be multiple entries of calendardate. These entries have a typical interval between them (say, 5 minutes, or 1 hour, etc). This interval may vary sometimes.

How can we iterate through each unique datetime value in the `calendardate` column (let's call it N), and for each value N get an array with the the value N, plus the values of columns code, A, B and C such that if either A, B or C is equal to -1, then we get the most recent previous value of A, B or C that is not -1 associated with that same code?

In other words, I want to print out each slice of the dataframe for each given datetime value with the most recent value of A, B and C up to N that are not -1.

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'code': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1'],
    'calendardate': [
        '2024-02-29 09:00:00', '2024-02-29 09:05:00', '2024-02-29 09:10:00', '2024-02-29 09:15:00',
        '2024-02-29 09:20:00', '2024-02-29 09:25:00', '2024-02-29 09:00:00', '2024-02-29 09:05:00',
        '2024-02-29 09:10:00', '2024-02-29 09:15:00'
    ],
    'A': [10, -1, 20, -1, 30, 40, 50, -1, -1, 60],
    'B': [-1, 15, -1, 25, -1, 35, -1, 45, -1, -1],
    'C': [-1, -1, -1, 35, -1, -1, -1, -1, 55, 65]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['calendardate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['calendardate'])

# Define a function to fill missing values with the most recent non-missing value for each column independently
def forward_fill(group):
    # Sort the group by 'calendardate' in ascending order
    group = group.sort_values(by='calendardate')

    # Forward fill missing values in column A, B and C
    group['A'] = group['A'].replace(-1, pd.NA).ffill()
    group['B'] = group['B'].replace(-1, pd.NA).ffill()
    group['C'] = group['C'].replace(-1, pd.NA).ffill()
    return group

# Apply the function within each group defined by 'calendardate'
filled_df = df.groupby('calendardate').apply(forward_fill).reset_index(drop=True)

# Iterate through each row and print the values for columns A, B, and C
for index, row in filled_df.iterrows():
    print("Datetime:", row['calendardate'])
    print("Code:", row['code'])
    print("A:", row['A'])
    print("B:", row['B'])
    print("C:", row['C'])
    print("------------------------")
```

It is very close, but for the first three iterations I get this:

```
Datetime: 2024-02-29 09:00:00
Code: A1
A: 10
B: <NA>
C: nan
------------------------
Datetime: 2024-02-29 09:00:00
Code: B1
A: 50
B: <NA>
C: nan
------------------------
Datetime: 2024-02-29 09:05:00
Code: A1
A: nan
B: 15
C: nan
```

When the third iteration should have printed:

```
Datetime: 2024-02-29 09:05:00
Code: A1
A: 10
B: 15
C: nan
```

Because for column A there was a value prior to timestamp `2024-02-29 09:05:00` that was not -1 (so the most recent non -1 value should be printed instead of `NaN`).

How can I accomplish this in Pandas? I'm using version 2.2.1

Thank you!

Comment: Your attempt code does not run. The code is similar to the AI's, but did you write it yourself?

Comment: I used AI to generate the sample dataframe and the prints at the end,  just because my code is more involved and this helped build a small repro for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `ffill` based on grouping by `code`, not by `calendardate`. Then you can sort the resultant df by `calendardate`:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df[cols] = df.replace(-1, np.nan).groupby('code')[cols].ffill()
df = df.sort_values('calendardate')
```

Output:

```
  code         calendardate     A     B     C
0   A1  2024-02-29 09:00:00  10.0   NaN   NaN
6   B1  2024-02-29 09:00:00  50.0   NaN   NaN
1   A1  2024-02-29 09:05:00  10.0  15.0   NaN
7   B1  2024-02-29 09:05:00  50.0  45.0   NaN
2   A1  2024-02-29 09:10:00  20.0  15.0   NaN
8   B1  2024-02-29 09:10:00  50.0  45.0  55.0
3   A1  2024-02-29 09:15:00  20.0  25.0  35.0
9   B1  2024-02-29 09:15:00  60.0  45.0  65.0
4   A1  2024-02-29 09:20:00  30.0  25.0  35.0
5   A1  2024-02-29 09:25:00  40.0  35.0  35.0
```